# jQuery .wrapAll() and .unwrap() issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first part of this script where it wraps some divs and adds a new class works fine.

**HTML** (This link opens ColorBox)

```
<a class="group1 cboxElement wrapbox" href="http://localhost/blabla">This is a link</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".wrapbox").click(function(){
   $('#boxOverlay, #box').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">');
   $("#boxOverlay").addClass("unwrapbox"); 

  });
});
```

But when I'm trying to make everything undo, the script fails and I have no clue why:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".unwrapbox").click(function(){
   $('#boxOverlay, #box').unwrap('<div class="wrapper">');
   $("#boxOverlay").removeClass("unwrapbox"); 

  });
});
```

**HTML:** (This is the result after I clicked ".unwrapbox")

```
<div class="wrapbox">
<div id="boxOverlay" class="unwrap" style="display: none; opacity: 1; cursor: auto; visibility:  visible;"></div>
<div id="colorbox" class="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: none; visibility: visible; top: 1125px; left: 660px; position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 1242px; opacity: 1; cursor: auto;">
```

Comment: Please post the HTML that this is being applied to and whenever possible, a jsFiddle example.

Comment: unwrapbox class is dynamic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unwrap doesn't take arguments.
http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

```
$(".unwrapbox").click(function(){
 $('#boxOverlay').unwrap();
});
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. That works for me too, but not when I run it on my localhost with Wordpress. Guess I have to doublecheck everything again.

Comment: Ok, figuered out now that the script only works when I put it in the footer. In the header it's being ignored. Weird...